# Create a heatmap with Pandas/Seaborn when one column is a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

Trying to create a heatmap with this data, and there are a few problems I can't solve. On the x-axis I want the Location, and the y-axis I want the Passengers. Those axises should not have duplicates, and with the x-axis (Location) it's easy to use the drop.duplicates(), but for the y-axis (Passengers) it doesn't work that well. The main problem is that the Passenger column that has multiple entries in a cell. Is there a good way to solve this? **Edit** I also need to get rid of the empty cells

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from collections.abc import Iterable
%matplotlib inline

file = "vacation.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)

example = df.filter(['Location', 'Passengers'])
print(example)

#x_axis = df.filter(['Location']).drop.duplicates() //Drop duplicates
```

Output:

```
Location                    Passengers
0     Paris                     []
1     Paris                     []
2     Stockholm                 []
3     Berlin                ['Peter']
4     Berlin                ['Maria, Debra, Kim']
...                             ...                    ...
2238  Helsinki              ['Peter, Maria']
2239  Berlin                ['Debra']
2240  Berlin                ['Debra']
2241  Helsinki              ['Debra']
2242  Paris                 ['Peter', 'Debra', 'Kim', 'Maria']

[2243 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: did you try `df.drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: yes, it drops the duplicates, but I need to "build" a y-axis, and get rid of the list of lists and just keep unique Passengers

Answer (score 0):

You can convert list to columns as follows, but check if it's valid for your case.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

---

```
def keep_one(row):
  unique = {}

  for val in row:
    unique[val] = None
    
  return list(unique.keys())
```

---

```
df['passengers_col'] = df['passengers_col'].apply(keep_one)

keys = np.unique(df['passengers_col'].apply(pd.Series).dropna()).astype('str').tolist()

cols_val = df['passengers_col'].apply(pd.Series).to_numpy().tolist()

new_cols = pd.DataFrame(data=cols_val, columns=keys)
```

---

```
# encode values
for k in new_cols.keys():
  indices = np.where(new_cols[k] != k)[0].tolist()
  new_cols.iloc[indices] = 0
```

---

Then you can use `pd.concat` to merge all columns with `new_cols` `DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but maybe this approach could help you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.DataFrame([["Paris",[]],["Paris",[]],
                     ["Stockholm",[]],["Berlin",['Peter']],
                     ["Berlin",['Maria', 'Debra', 'Kim']],["Helsinki",['Peter, Maria']],
                     ["Berlin",['Debra']],["Berlin",['Debra']],
                     ["Helsinki",['Debra']],["Paris",['Peter', 'Debra', 'Kim', 'Maria']]], columns = {"Location", "Passengers"})

data = data.groupby(["Location"]).sum()
cols = np.unique(np.sum(data["Passengers"]))

for col in cols:
    data[col] = 0
    
for idx in data.index:
    for col in data.loc[idx,"Passengers"]:
        data.loc[idx,col] += 1
        
sns.heatmap(data.iloc[:,1::])
```

Probably you could improve performance by removing loops if your dataset is big.

It outputs the following:

[image]

Comment: Looks promising! I get this though:

NameError: name 'cols' is not defined

Comment: Missing line, try it now

Comment: It works! I was using dummy-data for this, but the principle with the real data would be the same. Thank you very much for the help. If I could up-vote twice I would :)